# Codeigniter SQL join

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables:

> Table 1: dispatch_lists = id, date_of_dispatch, customer_id
>
> Table 2: dispatch_lists_rates - id, dispatch_list_id, item_id, weight, rate

I am trying to get list of records from `dispatch_lists_rates` table that corresponds to `dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch >= $start_date` and `dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch <= $end_date` (Basically, I'm trying to get list of items sold during a particular month, along with their rates)

Here is my code:

```
$this->db->select('dispatch_lists_rates.*, dispatch_lists.customer_id, dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch')
 ->from('dispatch_lists_rates')                 
 ->where('dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch >= '.$start_date)             
 ->where('dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch <= '.$end_date)           
 ->join('dispatch_lists', 'dispatch_lists_rates.dispatch_list_id = dispatch_lists.id');
```

This doesn't seem to work!
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your time!

[edit] I just realized I had the code quite wrong:

```
    ->where('dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch >= '.$start_date)  
should have been  
     ->where('dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch >= ', $start_date)
```

Thank you for trying to help!
Much Appreciated!

Comment: Glad that your problem got solved. But the syntax you have used doesn't seem to be correct. It is misguiding the community users. Just by correcting the question will not help. Please accept one of the below answers or answer the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, both the answers seem to be wrong. Marking either as correct would possibly misguide others.

Comment: Then prove it by answering your own question and accept it to help others. Editing question isn't helping others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
->where('dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch >= '.$start_date)
```

should be

```
 ->where('dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch >= ', $start_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `where` condition after `joins`

Please refer below code

```
$result = $this->db->select('dispatch_lists_rates.*, dispatch_lists.customer_id, dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch')
 ->from('dispatch_lists_rates')
 ->join('dispatch_lists', 'dispatch_lists_rates.dispatch_list_id = dispatch_lists.id');       
 ->where('dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch >= ', $start_date)             
 ->where('dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch <= ', $end_date)
 ->get();
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept my answer to support the community.

Answer (score 0):

Try it code:

```
$this->db->select('dispatch_lists_rates.*, dispatch_lists.customer_id, 
                    dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch');

$this->db->from('dispatch_lists_rates');

$this->db->join('dispatch_lists', 'dispatch_lists_rates.dispatch_list_id = 
                dispatch_lists.id');

$this->db->where(array('dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch' >= $start_date, 
                        'dispatch_lists.date_of_dispatch' <= $end_date));

$query = $this->db->get();
```